# Hot to disable key shortcut for "alt +tilde"

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, unity-dash, window-manager

I am comfortable using <kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>down</kbd> after typing <kbd>alt</kbd>+ <kbd>tab</kbd>, so I don't need the shortcut <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to do that.  And this is my favourite shortcut for maybe my most heavily used emacs command.

How can I disable it (not knowing how this key is named is not helping me; in my Spanish keyboard has a symbol I don't even know how to translate :-) )?

Comment: You should have simply typed the symbol instead :P
Its called 'backtick' (`).

Comment: Thanks! The common name allowed me to google (in my keyboard there is another symbol, and the backtick is somewhere else).  I found that there is related bug that prevented me to find the shortcut.  Here the bug and the workaround I used: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/874734

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answer my own question so it does not remain unanswered, but credit goes to Chirag64 for giving me the clue.

There is a bug that makes unity to activate that keybinding for that action when action is Disabled (as it is by default).  Workaround is to Enable the action and to assign it another keybinding.

See here the whole set of details: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/874734